# How to kill an application with a application NAME not process name

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, kill

I have a program that retrieves a list of applications like so

```
string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

            int id = -1;

            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
            {
                foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                    {
                        subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"))
```

This code above will return the name of the application for example Google will give me an output of "Google Chrome" not "chrome.exe" I'm putting these into a list and giving the option to checkmark them to exit on startup. I can't find a way to either kill an application with the output "Google Chrome" or find a way to get all application process from the PC without having to run every program to get them.

Answer (score 1):

The above code will give you the names of the applications as they show up in the control panel's "Programs and Features" list. If you query the `UninstallString` value of the same key, you'll get the command to uninstall said application. But there's no link from these names to the executables that make up the given application (this could be multiple as well).

This list from the registry is unsuitable for your purpose. You could check for running processes instead, or list the entries of the start menu, or check the autostart entries instead - to name a few better options.

Answer (score 1):

In case your task is to kill or exit all running processes with a certain name you might just invoke [GetProcessByName(string processName)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=net-5.0) to get all process instances  that match that name. And in case you get an non empty array of instances returned, invoke [Close()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.close?view=net-5.0) or [Kill()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-5.0) on each of them.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) 
{
    Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`"";
    exit;
}

Get-Process

$processName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Process name to kill'

if ($processName) 
{
    Stop-Process -Name $processName
}
```